# Inúmeras condições if e else

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho 5 campos `input` onde devo colocar um número qualquer, e dois botões: um com o nome maior e o outro com o nome menor.

Ao clicar no botão maior, preciso que ele me diga qual o campo onde se encontra o maior número digitado, e quando clicar no botão "menor", ele me diga qual o menor número digitado. Ele também tem que dar a informação de que algum campo esteja vazio caso o usuário não coloque nada lá.

Eu fiz o HTML e JavaScript, mas nao estou conseguindo finalizar:

```js
function Maior() {
    var numero1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("num1").value);
    var numero2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("num2").value);
    var numero3 = parseInt(document.getElementById("num3").value);
    var numero4 = parseInt(document.getElementById("num4").value);
    var numero5 = parseInt(document.getElementById("num5").value);

    //Verifico se os campos foram preenchidos
    if (!numero1 || !numero2 || !numero3 || !numero4 || !numero5) {
        alert("Preencha todos os campos.");

    } else {
        //Se foram preenchidos verifico qual é o menor
        if (numero1 < numero2 < numero3 < numero4 < numero5)
            alert("O número 1 possui o menor valor.");
        else if (numero2 < numero1 < numero3 < numero4 < numero5)
            alert("O número 2 possui o menor valor.");
        else if (numero3 < numero1 < numero2 < numero4 < numero5)
            alert("O número 3 possui o menor valor.");  
        else if (numero4 < numero1 < numero2 < numero3 < numero5)
            alert("O número 4 possui o menor valor.");
        else if (numero5 < numero1 < numero2 < numero3 < numero4)
            alert("O número 5 possui o menor valor.");          
        else if (numero1 == numero2)
            alert("Os valores dos número 1 e 2 são iguais.");
        else if (numero1 == numero3)
            alert("Os valores dos número 1 e 3 são iguais.");
        else if (numero1 == numero4)
            alert("Os valores dos número 1 e 4 são iguais.");
        else if (numero1 == numero5)
            alert("Os valores dos número 1 e 5 são iguais.");
        else if (numero2 == numero3)
            alert("Os valores dos número 2 e 3 são iguais.");
        else if (numero2 == numero4)
            alert("Os valores dos número 2 e 4 são iguais.");
        else if (numero2 == numero2)
            alert("Os valores dos número 2 e 5 são iguais.");
        else if (numero3 == numero4)
            alert("Os valores dos número 3 e 4 são iguais.");
        else if (numero3 == numero5)
            alert("Os valores dos número 3 e 5 são iguais.");
        else if (numero4 == numero5)
            alert("Os valores dos número 4 e 5 são iguais.");
        else
            alert("O número 2 possui o menor valor.");
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Calculadora Maior Menor com 5 Opções</title>
    <script src="js/calcMaiorMenor.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilo.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="calc-menor-maior">
        <h1>Calculadora com 5 Opções</h1>
        <div>
            <label for="">Número 1:</label>
            <input id="num1" type="number" placeholder="Número 1">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="">Número 2:</label>
            <input id="num2" type="number" placeholder="Número 2">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="">Número 3:</label>
            <input id="num3" type="number" placeholder="Número 3">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="">Número 4:</label>
            <input id="num4" type="number" placeholder="Número 4">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="">Número 5:</label>
            <input id="num5" type="number" placeholder="Número 5">
        </div>
        <div>
            <button onclick="Maior()">Maior</button>
            <button onclick="Menor()">Menor</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

Achar o maior ou menor com base em `ifs` e `elses` acaba por ser muito extenso e repetitivo, e não é uma solução escalável para uma quantidade considerável de números.

Para além disso a comparação que estava a fazer não era válida:

```
if (numero1 < numero2 < numero3 < numero4 < numero5)
```

Cada comparação tem de ter dois operandos, e por isso este mesmo `if` teria que ser:

```
if (numero1 < numero2 && numero1 < numero3 && numero1 < numero4 && numero1 < numero5)
```

No entanto a única solução comportável é com arrays. O mais direto será então utilizar [`Math.max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max), [`Math.min`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min) e um array para guardar os inputs e respetivos valores. Para criar um array com os valores de cada input pode faze-lo manualmente inserindo um a um com [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push). Para tornar o código mais curto e menos repetitivo demonstro o mesmo utilizando [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

Implementação:

```js
//obter os inputs todos e guardar num "array" (NodeList)
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll("#num1, #num2, #num3, #num4, #num5");

//função para validar se todos os inputs estão preenchidos
function inputsValidos(){
   for (let input of inputs){
     if(input.value == "" || isNaN(input.value)){
        return false;
     }
   }
   return true;
}

function Maior(){
   if (inputsValidos(inputs)){
     //mapear todos os inputs para um array de numeros utilizando map e parseInt
     const nums = [...inputs].map(n => parseInt(n.value));
     //obter o maximo com Math.max e passando a expansão do array
     console.log(Math.max(...nums)); 
   }
   else {
     console.log("Preencha todos os campos.");
   }
}

function Menor(){
   if (inputsValidos(inputs)){
     const nums = [...inputs].map(n => parseInt(n.value));
     console.log(Math.min(...nums)); //neste caso igual mas usando o min em vez de max
   }
   else {
     console.log("Preencha todos os campos.");
   }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Calculadora Maior Menor com 5 Opções</title>
    <script src="js/calcMaiorMenor.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilo.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="calc-menor-maior">
        <h1>Calculadora com 5 Opções</h1>
        <div>
            <label for="">Número 1:</label>
            <input id="num1" type="number" placeholder="Número 1">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="">Número 2:</label>
            <input id="num2" type="number" placeholder="Número 2">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="">Número 3:</label>
            <input id="num3" type="number" placeholder="Número 3">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="">Número 4:</label>
            <input id="num4" type="number" placeholder="Número 4">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="">Número 5:</label>
            <input id="num5" type="number" placeholder="Número 5">
        </div>
        <div>
            <button onclick="Maior()">Maior</button>
            <button onclick="Menor()">Menor</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Analisando em detalhe as duas instruções que calculam o máximo:

```
const nums = [...inputs].map(n => parseInt(n.value));
console.log(Math.min(...nums));
```

Aqui começamos por transformar o `NodeList` que sai do `querySelectorAll` num array normal com:

```
[...inputs]
```

O objetivo é conseguir utilizar a função `map` que não é possível de utilizar sobre um `NodeList` diretamente.
Os `...` correspondem ao [*Spread operator*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) que expande os elementos todos no próprio local.

Depois mapeamos cada `<input>` com `map`:

```
.map(n =>
```

O mapeamento é feito para a conversão em numero do valor que está escrito no campo:

```
parseInt(n.value)
```

Depois o máximo é calculado expandindo os elementos para a função `Math.max`:

```
Math.max(...nums)
```

Isto funciona pois esta função pode receber tantos números quantos necessários, que irá sempre devolver o maior. Para o mínimo o processo foi igual, mas trocando `max` por `min`.

Como observação final, repare que esta solução tanto funciona para achar o máximo de `5` inputs, como de `500`, garantindo que os seleciona apropriadamente na primeira linha de código. Se utilizar uma classe ao invés de `ids` individuais, então funciona direto sem precisar de alterar uma unica linha de código que seja.

Comment: Legal Isac. Obrigado por dispender do seu tempo para me ajudar.

Comment: @E.MC. Sem problema, estamos cá para isso mesmo

Answer (score 0):

Mesmo resultado com uma função genérica.

```js
function fMaiorMenor(op){
 var num_1 = document.getElementById('num1'),
 num_2 = document.getElementById('num2'),
 num_3 = document.getElementById('num3'),
 num_4 = document.getElementById('num4'),
 num_5 = document.getElementById('num5'),
 numFinal = 0;
 
 if( num_1.value == undefined || num_1.value == null || num_1.value == '' ){
  alert('Preencha o campo Número 1!');num_1.focus();return false;
 }
 else if( num_2.value == undefined || num_2.value == null || num_2.value == '' ){
  alert('Preencha o campo Número 2!');num_2.focus();return false;
 }
 else if( num_3.value == undefined || num_3.value == null || num_3.value == '' ){
  alert('Preencha o campo Número 3!');num_3.focus();return false;
 }
 else if( num_4.value == undefined || num_4.value == null || num_4.value == '' ){
  alert('Preencha o campo Número 4!');num_4.focus();return false;
 }
 else if( num_5.value == undefined || num_5.value == null || num_5.value == '' ){
  alert('Preencha o campo Número 5!');num_5.focus();return false;
 }
 else{
  numFinal = num_1.value;
  if( parseInt(op) == 1 ){
   if( parseInt(num_2.value) > parseInt(numFinal) ){
    numFinal = num_2.value;
   }
   if( parseInt(num_3.value) > parseInt(numFinal) ){
    numFinal = num_3.value;
   }
   if( parseInt(num_4.value) > parseInt(numFinal) ){
    numFinal = num_4.value;
   }
   if( parseInt(num_5.value) > parseInt(numFinal) ){
    numFinal = num_5.value;
   }
   alert('O Maior número é : '+numFinal.toString() );
  }
  else if( parseInt(op) == 2 ){
   if( parseInt(num_2.value) < parseInt(numFinal) ){
    numFinal = num_2.value;
   }
   if( parseInt(num_3.value) < parseInt(numFinal) ){
    numFinal = num_3.value;
   }
   if( parseInt(num_4.value) < parseInt(numFinal) ){
    numFinal = num_4.value;
   }
   if( parseInt(num_5.value) < parseInt(numFinal) ){
    numFinal = num_5.value;
   }
   alert('O Menor número é : '+numFinal.toString() );
  }
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="calc-menor-maior">
        <h1>Calculadora com 5 Opções</h1>
        <div>
            <label for="">Número 1:</label>
            <input id="num1" name="num1" type="number" placeholder="Número 1">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="">Número 2:</label>
            <input id="num2" name="num2" type="number" placeholder="Número 2">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="">Número 3:</label>
            <input id="num3" name="num3" type="number" placeholder="Número 3">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="">Número 4:</label>
            <input id="num4" name="num4" type="number" placeholder="Número 4">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="">Número 5:</label>
            <input id="num5" name="num5" type="number" placeholder="Número 5">
        </div>
        <div>
            <button onclick="fMaiorMenor(1)">Maior</button>
            <button onclick="fMaiorMenor(2)">Menor</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```